# Text Based Game Project

Tags: python

I am working on a simple game where you move from room to room and pick up items. You have to pick up all of the items before going to the final "boss" to win.

I have the room-to-room navigation down, but I am stuck with how to pick up items. I can't figure out where I am going wrong. If I enter an item or the item name, or 'item name' even. It says: there's no {item} here. Invalid command.
and asks me to enter my next move.

Here is my code. Any help is GREATLY appreciated!!

```py
#setting up the gameplay
def game_instructions():
   print('---------------------------')
   print("Welcome to Devin's epic battle")
   print("Help Devin collect 6 items to defeat Kevin the Great White Shark")
   print("Move through the reef using: 'north', 'south', 'east', or 'west'")
   print("Each new room you enter will contain one item vital to help you defeat Kevin. \nUse command: 'take item'")
   print("\nGood Luck!")

rooms = {
   'Anemone House' : {'east': 'Crab Lagoon', 'south': 'Octopus Reef', 'item': 'no items'},
   'Crab Lagoon' : {'west': 'Anemone House', 'east': 'Shipwreck Cove', 'item': 'Josh the Crab'},
   'Shipwreck Cove' : {'west': 'Crab Lagoon', 'item': 'Golden Anchor'},
   'Octopus Reef' : {'north': 'Anemone House', 'east': 'Kelp Forest', 'south': 'Ocean Trench', 'item': 'Coral'},
   'Kelp Forest' : {'west': 'Octopus Reef', 'south': 'Shark Reef','item': 'Bottle with Map'},
   'Ocean Trench' : {'north': 'Octopus Reef', 'west': 'Spooky Cave', 'east': 'Shark Reef', 'item': 'Magic Net'},
   'Spooky Cave' : {'east': 'Ocean Trench', 'item': 'Mindy the Stingray'},
   'Shark Reef' : {'west': 'Ocean Trench', 'item': 'Kevin the Shark!'} #badguy
}


def player_status():   #room and inventory
   print('\n---------------------------')
   print('You are in the {}'.format(current_room))
   print('In this room, you find {}'.format(rooms[current_room]['item']))
   print('Inventory: {}'.format(inventory_item))
   print('---------------------------')

def invalid_move():
   print('You cannot go this way. Please try again.')

def invalid_item():
   print('Item is not found in this part of the reef')
   player_status()


game_instructions()

inventory_item = []
current_room = 'Anemone House'
command = ''

while current_room != 'Shark Reef':
   player_status()
   command = input('Enter next move.\n').lower()
   if command == 'take item':
      item = input('Which item do you want to take?').lower()
      if item in rooms[current_room]['item']:
         inventory_item.append(item)
         rooms[current_room]['item'] = 'no items'
      else:
         print(f"There's no {item} here.")
   elif command not in rooms[current_room]:
      invalid_move()
   elif 'item' in rooms[current_room] and command == 'take item':
      invalid_item()
   else:
      current_room = rooms[current_room][command]

if len(inventory_item) != 6:
   print('Oh no, Kevin defeated you!')
else:
   print('You did it! You defeated Kevin!')
```

Answer (score 0):

> *"... If I enter an item or the item name, or 'item name' even. It says: there's no {item} here. Invalid command. ..."*

You're using the *str.lower* method on your input value.
Thus, when searching for a value, the key is incorrect.

```py
item = input('Which item do you want to take?').lower()
```

For example, the *key* is *"Josh the Crab"*, yet any input value would result in *"josh the crab"*, hence, is not found.

Comment: Ok, thank you for explaining that, that makes sense. if I take it out and just use:
item = input('Which item do you want to take?')

I still receive the same errors.

Comment: @cupcakesncode, it works here, _"Inventory: ['Josh the Crab', 'Coral']"_.  What other error are you encountering?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this part of your code:

```py
   if command == 'take item':
      item = input('Which item do you want to take?').lower()
      if item in rooms[current_room]['item']:
         inventory_item.append(item)
         rooms[current_room]['item'] = 'no items'
```

See, you are checking if your key.lower() is in the items, but as you know, your items mostly all contain uppercase letters. Instead, you should do:

```
   if command == 'take item':
      item = input('Which item do you want to take?').lower()
      items = list(map(str.lower, rooms[current_room]['item']))
      if item in items:
         inventory_item.append(item)
         rooms[current_room]['item'] = 'no items'
```

Comment: I tried adding the code you suggested, but I am still receiving the Invalid Command Error and it won't add the item to my inventory.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this part of your code.

```
if command == 'take item':
  item = input('Which item do you want to take?').lower()
  if item in rooms[current_room]['item']:
     inventory_item.append(item)
     rooms[current_room]['item'] = 'no items'
  else:
     print(f"There's no {item} here.")
```

First, your input is always converted to lower case. Second, it checks if the item is in the `rooms[current_room]['item']`, which it is a single item not an array of items. Therefore, you need to fix this to something like this.

```
if command == 'take item':
  item = input('Which item do you want to take?').lower()
  if item == rooms[current_room]['item'].lower():
     inventory_item.append(item)
     rooms[current_room]['item'] = 'no items'
  else:
     print(f"There's no {item} here.")
```

You fix the first issue of the lower case input by converting the data into lower case too, so that it works for all possibilities of either lower cases or  upper cases. After you ensure that the input item and the item in the room have the same pattern that will match when compared, you fix the comparison part by changing `in` to `==` so that it actually compares two strings.